# Uupdate values in two tables via stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have two tables and I need to update values in them via a stored procedure. Tried too much to update but some times it update the first table only, others the second or even fail due to cannot allow duplicates. Also when it updates the WHOLE data in the table becomes the same as the new updated ones. I've now reached to this error after all these lines of codes

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Emp_ID',table 'DatePics'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.The statement has been terminated

Here is the **SQL** code :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[UpdateEmp]
    @EmpName nvarchar(100),
    @Nationality nvarchar(30),    
    @Passport nvarchar(20),
    @ContractDate date,
    @HealthDate date
AS
BEGIN 
    set nocount on;

DECLARE @IDs table (ID int )
UPDATE Employee SET 
EmpName=@EmpName, Nationality=@Nationality, Visa=@Visa, Passport=@Passport,
ReceivedDate=@ReceivedDate,IDIssue=@IDIssue, IDExpiry=@IDExpiry, Sponsor=@Sponsor
output inserted.ID into @IDs (ID)
WHERE ID = @ID

UPDATE DatePics SET
FingerDate=@FingerDate, ContractDate=@ContractDate, HealthDate=@HealthDate
where Emp_ID in (select ID from @IDs);
END
```

After writing the stored procedure code, I wrote the C# code like this:

```
private void updatebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = db.con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "UpdateEmp";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", NameSeartxt.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nationality", NatSeartxt.Text);            
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passport", PassSeartxt.Text);            
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractDate", ContractSeartxt.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HealthDate", HealthSeartxt.Text);

        db.con.Open();
        int up = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (up > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Update done ", "DONE !");
            SearNametxt.Text = "";
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to update", "FAIL !");
            SearNametxt.Text = "";
        }
        db.con.Close();
    }
```

Any clue?

Comment: If 'DatePics' is not required parameter (not always provided) change your datable so that 'DatePics' allow NULL's.

Comment: this is the FK in the second table and cannot be null

Answer (score 2):

I can see three problems with your query. 1 You declare ID, but don't assign it before using it, so it will always be NULL for the first query, so this will never update any rows:

```
DECLARE @ID int 

UPDATE FrstTable SET 
EmpName=@EmpName, Nationality=@Nationality, Passport=@Passport
WHERE ID = @ID
```

Secondly, you are using `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to attempt to get the ID of the record that has been updated. You can't do that, SCOPE_IDENTITY will return the last inserted ID, it is not affected by updates. You will need to use OUTPUT to get the Updated ID:

```
DECLARE @IDs TABLE (ID INT);

UPDATE  FirstTable
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @Ids (ID)
SET     EmpName = @EmpName, 
        Nationality = @Nationality, 
        Passport = @Passport;
```

Thirdly, your second update statement has no where clause, so will update the entire table:

```
UPDATE  ScndTable 
SET     Emp_ID=@ID, ContractDate=@ContractDate, HealthDate=@HealthDate
WHERE   EmpID IN (SELECT ID FROM @Ids);
```

Comment: tried this code, I will edit my original post with it

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure looks weird to me. I believe there should be a `WHERE` cluase for the second `UPDATE` otherwise it will always update the whole `ScndTable` table. `set @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();` seems to be reduntant here. Are you trying to perform insert into ScndTable if there's no corresponding Emp_ID there? Finnaly explicitly create a transaction to update either both tables or none.

Hope it helps!

Comment: `UPDATE FrstTable SET 
EmpName=@EmpName, Nationality=@Nationality, Passport=@Passport
WHERE ID = @ID

UPDATE ScndTable SET 
ContractDate=@ContractDate, HealthDate=@HealthDate
where Emp_ID=@ID`
Tried this one, but no update occur

Answer (score 0):

Please assign the value of @ID variable, before executing the first update statement.

I think you are trying to update some row, so you can pass the 'id' value from the CSHARP code. When you use the SCOPE_IDENTITY, you will get the last inserted value. Try to pass the ID value from the front end.